# JEXL3 - Unabled to override bitwiseXor in JexlArithemtic?

Tags: java, kotlin, jexl

I use JEXL3 to convert user input as string to a math function, I would like to use `^` as `Math.pow()` so I read about extending `JexlArithemtic` to override `bitwiseXor` like here: http://apache-commons.680414.n4.nabble.com/JEXL-Evaluating-math-expression-td4112606.html

This example is for Jexl2 and I use Jexl3, if I try to override:

```
class JexlArithmeticWithPow(lenient: Boolean) : JexlArithmetic(lenient) {

    override fun bitwiseXor(left: Any, right: Any): Any { //bitwiseXor is final and cannot be overriden
        val l = toDouble(left)
        val r = toDouble(right)
        return Math.pow(l, r)
    }

}
```

Is there another possibility to convert `^`to `Math.pow` instead of `bitwiseXor`?

Answer (score 0):

In JEXL3, the JexlArithmetic method bitwiseXor has been deprecated (and made final); replacement method is `public Object xor(Object left, Object right);`.
Note that with JEXL3, you may want to only add an overload to that method for numbers, ie `public Object xor(Number left, Number right);`.